# Why am I getting a repeat answer?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am just learning python and have got onto if / while statement, this basic program is meant to determine if a bar of chocolate could be split into x amount of pieces only using the rows existing.

It works 99% of the time however occasionally I get a result of YES YES. example of this below.
(useless is just a placeholder I use to end IF statements I don't have an else for.)

````
length = int(6)
chunks = int(6)
total = row*length
row_a = total
length_a = total
useless = 0
no = 0
if chunks == total:
    print("YES")
else:
    useless = useless +1
while row_a != 0:
    if chunks == total - row_a:
        print("YES")
        break
    else:
        row_a = row_a - row
        if row_a == 0:
            no = no+1
        else:
            useless = useless +1
while length_a != 0:
    if chunks == total - length_a:
        print("YES")
        break
    else:
        length_a = length_a - length
        if length_a == 0:
            no = no +1
        else: useless = useless +1
else: useless = useless +1
if no == 2:
    print("NO")
else: useless = useless +1 ```
````

Comment: Variable "row" is used but never set.

Comment: `row` is not defined. I suspect the first "YES" is from the `chunks==total` condition, the second "YES" is form the `chunks == total - length_a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you review the problem from the beginning and try to solve it before you start coding. Your code is too complex for a simple problem.

Here is an example of code that can solve the problem.

```
x, y = 8, 10 #length and width of the chocolate bar

p_s = 5 #pieces size
p_n = int(input('Number of pieces: '))

total=x*y #size of the chocolate bar

if total//p_s < p_n:
    print('NO')
else:
    print('YES')
```

Comment: I don't understand why your code works, I think it's more complex than the level I am at on my course, can you please just show me on my code what I need to do to remove the bonus yes.

Comment: @MrDDog This is a mathematical problem. ***Explanation*** [link](https://i.imgur.com/QQ3HHzc.png)